# PHP int comparison - why add 0 to the variables first?

Tags: php, integer, comparison

Easy question here.  Just wondering if there's something to learn from this code snippet, or not.

Found this in some legacy code...never seen it before, can't find anything about it online, and the developer is long gone.

```
if ($row['cnt']+0 !== $count+0) {
   // log warnings etc
}
```

My guess is ... no, actually I don't have a good guess about why the zeroes are added to the variables before comparison.  Any ideas?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: It casts the variable to an integer before the test.  PHP is weakly typed.

Comment: It's a way of forcing cast to integer

Comment: looks line voodoo, better use intval()

Comment: Instead of forcing to `INT` why not just use `!=` ?

Comment: @MarkBaker and phaedra I wondered if that was the case, but it only works on numeric strings so that made me doubt it, but you're right AbraCadaver I agree.  It's possibly a benchmark thing, maybe it was a tiny bit faster one way vs the other.

Comment: @billrichards - No, it will work on non-numeric strings as well, `"abc"+0` will give an integer `0`, so you can still do an integer comparison

Comment: @MarkBaker you're right...what I really meant was '3'+0 === 3+0 gives expected results, but 'abc'+0 === 3+0 does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's just an old way to do the int conversion:

```
php > var_dump('112'+0);
int(112)
```

by the way then :

```
php > echo ("0012"+0 === "12"+0 )? "yay!" : "booh!";
yay!
```

its pure trash, but works, the right way is like this:

```
php > var_dump((int)"324");
int(324)
```